# Programmatic (API calls) User Authentication using Azure AD B2C instead of login.microsoftoneline.com form

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

New to Azure AD... So please don't be too harsh if this is off target. :-)

Technology Stack - Latest Angular 2 with C# Middle tier and latest .Net Framework.

Ideally, What we want to do is use Azure AD B2C to store user credentials and to do the authentication - but we want our 'own' forms on our site to do the login Forms capture and logging - then pass the credentials through an API (REST?) Call (using MS Graph SDK?) to Azure AD B2C and then check the call return for the Authorization content message.

Couple of reasons - control of the application flow, Logging and the "flickering of the URL" (i.e. going from our site URL to login.microsoft... URL and then back to our sites URL).

Is this doable without doing a hack?

Thank you in advance for your help and patience!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the "[Resource Owner Password Credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.3)".

This is not currently supported for Azure AD B2C, but you can give user feedback to the B2C team that you want this through the Azure Feedback Forum: [Add support for Resource Owner Password Credentials flow in Azure AD B2C and headless authentication in Microsoft Authentication Library](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/13817784-add-support-for-resource-owner-password-credential)

You should also see updates at that location if and when they implement this feature.

Answer (score 1):

The resource owner password credentials flow is now in preview.

> In Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C, the following options are
> supported:
>
> Native Client: User interaction during authentication happens when
> code runs on a user-side device. The device can be a mobile
> application that's running in a native operating system, such as
> Android, or running in a browser, such as JavaScript.
>
> Public client flow: Only user credentials, gathered by an application, are sent in
> the API call. The credentials of the application are not sent.
>
> Add new claims: The ID token contents can be changed to add new claims.
>
> The following flows are not supported:
>
> Server-to-server: The identity protection system needs a reliable IP
> address gathered from the caller (the native client) as part of the
> interaction. In a server-side API call, only the server’s IP address
> is used. If a dynamic threshold of failed authentications is exceeded,
> the identity protection system may identify a repeated IP address as
> an attacker.
>
> Confidential client flow: The application client ID is
> validated, but the application secret is not validated.

From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-ropc).

Answer (score 0):

Note that one disadvantage of doing what you're requesting is precisely that you can do "login forms capture and logging", so your application has a chance to see the credentials and perhaps take copies of them; thus your users have to trust you to behave.

The normal web-based flow means that your application doesn't need to be trusted; it never even sees the password at all.